# How do I scroll up in the Excel window (not a worksheet window)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've just opened an excel worksheet, and it's appeared in a restored down window. I can't access the top of the window because it has opened off the top of the excel window (see image below). Is there a way to add scroll bars to the Excel window? or another way to access the top bar of the worksheet window?

I've got a workaround to maximize the window, but I need it restored down so that I can see it side-by-side with another worksheet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the VIEW tab, then Arrange all?

Comment: That should work. Alternatively, take you mouse to the top right corner of the worksheet. The cursor should change to a tilted double arrow (re-size symbol). You can then click and drag down to see the top of the worksheet window.

Comment: Thank you, RocketGoal - I had a feeling it would be something very simple...